# React useState поведение чекбокса

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);

  function handleChange() {
    console.log(checked);
    setChecked(!checked); // инвертируем стейт
    console.log(checked);
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log(checked);
    },3000)
  }

  return <div>
    <input type="checkbox" checked={checked} onChange={handleChange}
    />
    <p>{checked?'отмечен':'не отмечен'}</p>
    <button onClick={()=>console.log(checked)}>проверить</button>
  </div>;
}

export default App;
```

судя по консольлогу состояние чекбокса не меняется после срабатывания функции, а также таймер по истечении 3 секунд также говорит что состояние не изменилось, но если нажать на кнопку которая проверяет сотояние чекбокса то она покажет обратное что всетаки он изменился, даже если это будет до истечения этих 3 секунд. Почему так? что это за эффект? что гуглить чтобы понять в чем проблема?

Comment: Потому что setState - асинхронная функция https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как setState работает [асинхронно](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous), то в Вашем случае лучше использовать такой алгоритм:

```
function handleChange() {
  const newChecked = !checked; // Получаем новое значение заранее изменяя текущее
  setChecked(newChecked); // Обновляем состояние на новое
  console.log(`old = ${checked}; new = ${newChecked}`);
}
```